# How to format angular mat date picker value

Tags: angular, date, angular-material

I am using a mat date picker in my form and saving the value to my database. The value saves in this format: `2019-08-22T23:00:00`. I am fetching back these values from the database and binding them to form inputs using ngModel but i am having problem binding the date to the mat date picker.

Here is my HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
   <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Date of birth" 
   [ngModel]="user.dob | date " name='dob'>
   <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

I send the value from the above to a mysql database. I noticed that when i choose a date like 23rd August, 2019, it returns 22nd in this format `2019-08-22T23:00:00`. When I fetch back the data from my database and try to bind it to the date type input field above, it does not bind. How to make the date picker return the selected date and also how to bind the date to it in the format `dd-mm-yy`. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using firebase as the database? If so it might be due to conversion of date objects to timestamps. Otherwise can you share the code you are using?

Comment: @chrismclarke no. I use mysql database. I have updated my question.

Comment: Ok, in that case I think probably best to go with a formControl instead of ngModel. Will provide an example below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is use a form control. This can be bound either to the `value` field or a `formControl` field, i.e.:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-value-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-value-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-value-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerValueExample {
  date = new FormControl('2019-08-22T23:00:00');
}
```

*AppComponent.ts*

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Angular forms" [formControl]="date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker3" placeholder="Value binding" [value]="date.value">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker3"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker3></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

*AppComponent.html*

You can see a working blitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-umwtzi?file=app%2Fdatepicker-value-example.html

Or more documentation and examples from the material docs: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples

Comment: Thanks it worked. I was just thinking, what if i wanted to change the date format, like if i wanted it in the format `23rd August, 2019`. Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: That format wouldn't be recognisable as a date constructor paramater (i.e. new Date('23rd August, 2019') returns invalid) so it won't work. You would have to add your own manual methods to convert the string back into a date before binding, if that makes sense?

Comment: But if it was only the display you wanted to change, then yes there are ways to do that, see the last example at: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Will check it out